# Increase max retrievable items from PHP

Tags: soap-api, php

Good Day All,
   I am using a soapclient to access data from salesforce to php, and was able to retrieve data more than a thousand, however, php was only able to display 1000 but it did say that the length of the result is more than a thousand which is correct. any ideas on how I might increase the viewable items in php? (sorry, I am not that knowledgeable in terms of php that's why I am having these problems.)

Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Since the Salesforce API is behaving as expected, this question seems at first glance to be more of a PHP question, which might fit in more at Stack Overflow. If you feel like it belongs here, would you please [edit] this post to show us what you're doing in code? See [ask]. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's example code [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_11.0_QueryMore_and_QueryOptions_Sample_(Enterprise)).

```
<?php
// SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR - folder that contains the PHP Toolkit and your WSDL
// $USERNAME - variable that contains your Salesforce.com username (must be in the form of an email)
// $PASSWORD - variable that contains your Salesforce.ocm password

define("SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR", "../../soapclient");
require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');
require_once ('../../misc/globalconstants.php');

try {
  $mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
  $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/enterprise.wsdl.xml');
  $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);

  $query = 'SELECT NumberOfEmployees from Lead where NumberOfEmployees != null order by NumberOfEmployees';
  $options = new QueryOptions(200);
  $mySforceConnection->setQueryOptions($options);
  $response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
  !$done = false;

  echo "Size of records:  ".$response ->size;

  if ($response->size > 0) {
    while (!$done) {
      foreach ($response->records as $record) {
        echo $record->NumberOfEmployees."\r\n";
      }
      if ($response->done != true) {
        echo "***** Get Next Chunk *****\n";
        try {
          $response = $mySforceConnection->queryMore($response->queryLocator);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          print_r($mySforceConnection->getLastRequest());
          echo $e->faultstring;
        }
      } else {
        $done = true;
      }
    }
  }

} catch (Exception $e) {
  print_r($mySforceConnection->getLastRequest());
  echo $e->faultstring;
}
?>
```

Basically, while each query result has `done` set to `false`, there's more data to collect. Use the queryLocator to call queryMore and retrieve the next batch of data. Rinse and repeat until you have all the data.

Comment: thank you! I will try this code :)